# Outlook running as different windows user

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, file-sharing

Just encountered a user who in Outlook runs as a different profile abcd01 rather than dcba02.
This causes her attatched file to misbehave as user abcd01 is not allowed to touch dcba02.

Is there a way to fix this?

How do I change which user Outlook runs with?

Comment: Outlook profile or user profile?

Comment: User profile! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, you can grant a user permissions to another mailbox through Active Directory Users and Computers.

For your second question [runas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) should work in this scenario, if Shift + Right Click and "Run as different user" is not appropriate. For example

```
runas /user:DEATHSTAR\dvader "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE"
```

Comment: Hmm, should I really have to use this, works fine on other workstations

Comment: Are other workstations accessing files their user doesn't have permission to? That's the cause of your 'problem' :)

Comment: The wierd thing is that Outlook uses a different user then the logged in one

Comment: Any ideas, runas seems to be doing it wrong :S

Answer (score 0):

In the Control Panel under Mail you can add profiles to Outlook, and have the user choose which profile to use as outlook starts. These other profiles could be alternative accounts. For example I have an outlook profile set up to use my main work account and another to use our group shared account for when I want to triage crash reports.

[image: Mail profile setup]

You could also log in to Outlook as dcba02 and then give abcd01 full delegate access to the Exchange account.

[image: Delegate access]